# Problema ao carregar no load do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problema para carregar esse valores no load do jquery.

Segue o código.

Javascript:

```
 $('.buscando').click(function(){

            var id = document.getElementById('campo1').value;

            $("#cliente1").load('/wbahd/servico_servlet?acao=buscar&busca='+id);
          });
```

Este código faz a ação pega o parâmetro mas não faz o load da página.

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="busca">Nome Servico*:</label> <input id="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira um nome para busca">
    </div>
    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn buscando">Buscar</a>

    </div>
```

Obg.

Comment: Abra o console e veja se ocorreu algum erro, também se certifique que existe o elemento `<div id="cliente1"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método load() tem outros dois parâmetros opcionais que podemos utilizar, caso necessário, que se especificam com a típica notação de propriedades e valores de jQuery.

Por exemplo:  `{acao: "buscar", busca: id}`  com este código estaríamos enviando à página os dados <sub>**acao**</sub> e <sub>**busca**</sub>, com os valores <sub>**"buscar"**</sub> e <sub>**id**</sub>, sendo id a variável com valor passado pelo input. Esses dados viajam na URL, pelo método "POST".

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buscando").click(function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        var id = $('#campo1').val();
        $(".cliente1").load("/wbahd/servico_servlet", {acao: "buscar", busca: id}, function(){
        });
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cliente1"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="busca">Nome Servico*:</label> <input id="campo1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira um nome para busca">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default btn-cadastrar-btn buscando">Buscar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Obg leo . Funcionou perfeitamente.